# Vue: binding with v-model in custom checkbox component doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, vuejs2, v-model

I'm trying to build a custom checkbox component with options that are generated with a v-for loop from an array with options and values. How can I bind the v-model correctly to the checkbox component so that it's correctly updated?

The problem now is that the model only updates to the latest checkbox that is checked and does not give an array with all checked options.

```js
Vue.component('ui-checkbox', {
  props: {   
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    index: {
      type: Number
    },
    inputValue: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
    },
  },
 template: `<div>
    <input 
      :id="index"
      type="checkbox"
      :value="inputValue"
      @change="onChange" />
    <label :for="index">
      {{ label }}
    </label>
  </div>`,
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checkOptions: [
      {
        label: 'Option 1',
        value: 'value of option 1',
      },
      {
        label: 'Option 2',
        value: 'value of option 2',
      },
      {
        label: 'Option 3',
        value: 'value of option 3',
      },
      {
        label: 'Option 4',
        value: 'value of option 4',
      },
    ],
    myCheckBoxModel: []
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <span>checked Checkboxes: {{ myCheckBoxModel }} </span>
   <ui-checkbox
     v-for="(option, index) in checkOptions"
     v-model="myCheckBoxModel"
     :key="index"
     :index="index"
     :input-value="option.value"
     :label="option.label" />    
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

When you do

```
this.$emit('input', e.target.value);
```

it works like

```
myCheckBoxModel = e.target.value
```

So it just assigns the value of the last checkbox you clicked to `myCheckBoxModel`.
If you want to keep all checked items in `myCheckBoxModel`, you need to do the following:

1. add `value` property to `ui-checkbox` component to have access to the current value of `myCheckBoxModel`. `Value` is default property name for this goal (see [vue guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)).
2. in your `onChange` method copy the current value to the variable, because it's not good to mutate `value` property directly
3. if your checkbox is checked, push the correspondent value to the array. If the checkbox is not checked, delete to correspondent value from the array
4. emit `input` event with the resulting array as value

```js
Vue.component('ui-checkbox', {
         props: {   
        label: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        index: {
          type: Number
        },
        inputValue: {
          type: String
        },
        value: {
          type: Array
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onChange(e) {
          let currentValue = [...this.value]
          if (e.target.checked) {
            currentValue.push(e.target.value) 
          } else {
            currentValue = currentValue.filter(item => item !== e.target.value)
          }
          this.$emit('input', currentValue);
        },
      },
        template: `<div>
        <input 
          :id="index"
          type="checkbox"
          :value="inputValue"
          @change="onChange" />
        <label :for="index">
          {{ label }}
        </label>
      </div>`,
    })

    new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        checkOptions: [
          {
            label: 'Option 1',
            value: 'value of option 1',
          },
          {
            label: 'Option 2',
            value: 'value of option 2',
          },
          {
            label: 'Option 3',
            value: 'value of option 3',
          },
          {
            label: 'Option 4',
            value: 'value of option 4',
          },
        ],
       myCheckBoxModel: []
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <div id="app">
  checked Checkboxes:
       <span v-for="item in myCheckBoxModel"> {{ item }}; </span>
       <ui-checkbox
         v-for="(option, index) in checkOptions"
         v-model="myCheckBoxModel"
         :key="index"
         :index="index"
         :input-value="option.value"
         :label="option.label" />    
  </div>
```

I don't know if you need to set checkbox state programmatically, i.e. when you change `myCheckBoxModel` the state of checkboxes changes correspondently. If you do, you need to watch `value` property in your `ui-checkbox` component: set the state of the check box in dependance of if its value is in `value` array. Do the same also in `created` hook if you want to initialize the state of checkboxes by `myChexkboxModel`

Answer (score 8):

The solution presented by @Lana is just too complicated. The `onChange` method is not needed at all - what you want is to use build-in power of `v-model`. See below...

```js
Vue.component('ui-checkbox', {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    index: {
      type: Number
    },
    inputValue: {
      type: String
    },
    value: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  computed: {
    model: {
      get() {
        return this.value
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit('input', value)
      }
    },
  },
  template: `<div>
        <input 
          :id="index"
          type="checkbox"
          :value="inputValue"
          v-model="model" />
        <label :for="index">
          {{ label }}
        </label>
      </div>`,
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checkOptions: [{
        label: 'Option 1',
        value: 'value of option 1',
      },
      {
        label: 'Option 2',
        value: 'value of option 2',
      },
      {
        label: 'Option 3',
        value: 'value of option 3',
      },
      {
        label: 'Option 4',
        value: 'value of option 4',
      },
    ],
    myCheckBoxModel: []
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  model: {{ myCheckBoxModel }}
  <ui-checkbox v-for="(option, index) in checkOptions" v-model="myCheckBoxModel" :key="index" :index="index" :input-value="option.value" :label="option.label" />
</div>
```

NOTE that using `v-for` `index` as a `key` works in this case BUT is not recommended in general, especially if set of checkboxes is dynamic and can change over the lifetime of the component that is rendering them.

Comment: This is much cleaner, thank you!

Comment: hey @michal. I can't seem to get this to work with multiple checkboxes. It just seems to replace the selectedCheckbox array with whatever the last checkbox input value was even if its been unchecked. Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @ToddPadwick Without the code it is impossible to tell what's wrong. Anyway my example works with multiple checkboxes just fine...

Comment: @ToddPadwick Sounds like it would be an issue with your array transformation(s).